# #ckan PasteScript Error during CKan Migration from version 2.4 to 2.6

Tags: upgrade, ckan, paster

I'm upgrating from version 2.4 to version 2.6 using the documentation [link](http://docs.ckan.org/en/ckan-2.6.0/maintaining/upgrading/upgrade-source.html)

I'm getting the following paster error when executing the paster command

```
paster db upgrade -c /etc/ckan/default/production.ini

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/bin/paster", line 7, in
from paste.script.command import run
File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paste/script/command.py", line 54, in
dist = pkg_resources.get_distribution('PasteScript')
File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/distribute-0.6.24-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 330, in get_distribution
if isinstance(dist,Requirement): dist = get_provider(dist)
File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/distribute-0.6.24-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 209, in get_provider
return working_set.find(moduleOrReq) or require(str(moduleOrReq))[0]
File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/distribute-0.6.24-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 686, in require
needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/distribute-0.6.24-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 584, in resolve
raise DistributionNotFound(req)
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: PasteScript
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you didn't run the 'pip install' step (step 3)with an activated virtual environment. All these commands should be run with an activated virtual environment (step 1) so don't forget to do that again if you start a new terminal/shell.

Comment: Hello D Read, I ran the (step 3) with an activated virtual environment and after many tests I could not find a solution for it.
I upgraded to version 2.5.3 instead of 2.6 and it was fine.